# generate lambdas body (that invokes a callable and returns) depending on template type

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a callable object that might return `bool` or `void`. This object needs to be wrapped in a lambda. This lambda should always return `bool`. If the callable object returns `bool` then lambda return whatever is returned by the object. Otherwise (if object returns `void`) lambda just invokes it and returns `true`.

I tried to simplify the code below as much as possible.

```cpp
template<class... Params>
struct SParamsPack {};

template <class T> struct SFuncInfo {};

// in the simplified version specialization only for member function
template <class T, class R, class... FuncParams>
struct SFuncInfo<R(T::*)(FuncParams...)> {
    using Signature = std::function<bool(FuncParams...)>;
    using Ret = R;
    using Params = SParamsPack<FuncParams...>;
};

template<class T, class Func, class... Params>
SFuncInfo<Func>::Signature GenerateVoidLambda(Func f, T* pObj, SParamsPack<Params...>)
{
    return [pObj, f](Params&&... params) -> bool
    {
        (pObj->*f)(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
        return true;
    };
}

template<class T, class Func, class... Params>
SFuncInfo<Func>::Signature GenerateBoolLambda(Func f, T* pObj, SParamsPack<Params...>)
{
    return [pObj, f](Params&&... params) -> bool
    {
        return (pObj->*f)(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    };
}

// bodies of both WrapMemberFunction are almost identical
template<class T, class Func, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename SFuncInfo<Func>::Ret, bool>::value, bool> = true>
SFuncInfo<Func>::Signature WrapMemberFunction(Func f, T* pObj)
{
    return GenerateBoolLambda(f, pObj, SFuncInfo<Func>::Params());
}

template<class T, class Func, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename SFuncInfo<Func>::Ret, void>::value>>
SFuncInfo<Func>::Signature WrapMemberFunction(Func f, T* pObj)
{
    return GenerateVoidLambda(f, pObj, SFuncInfo<Func>::Params());
}

//! Registers a std::function that returns bool.
template<class... Params>
void RegisterCommand(const string& id, std::function<bool(Params...)> f)
{
    // Code for registration of command.
}

//! Registers a member function pointer as a command.
template<class T, class Func>
void RegisterCommand(const string& id, Func f, T* pObj)
{
    RegisterCommand(id, CommandRegistry::WrapMemberFunction(f, pObj));
}
```

The user's call would look like this:

```cpp
RegisterCommand("general.create", &SomeObj::OnCreate, pSomeObject);
```

The code should conform to C++14 standard.

So is there any way to make this code look nicer? Is it possible to get rid of at least of `WrapMemberFunction()` or `GenerateLambda()` methods?

Any other tips on how to simplify this code are much appreciated.

Comment: You have tagged C++11 but are using `std::invoke` from C++17?

Answer (score 2):

Non a great solution...

The best I can imagine is a single lambda with a `if constexpr` to separate the two cases (you tagged C++11 but you're using `std::invoke()`, so you're using C++17 so you can also use `if constexpr`)

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename ... Args>
typename SFuncInfo<F>::Signature GenerateLambda(F f, T* pObj,
                                                SParamsPack<Args...>)
 {
   return [pObj, f](Args && ... as) -> bool
    {
      if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<void,
                                    decltype(std::function{f})::result_type> )
       {
         std::invoke(f, pObj, std::forward<Args>(as)...);

         return true;
       }
      else
         return std::invoke(f, pObj, std::forward<Args>(as)...);
    };
 }
```

Comment: hey @max66, thanks for pointing this out. I completely overlooked the fact that std::invoke is C++17. The code should conform to C++14 (I edited the description) and so I had to switch to raw member function call.

Comment: @Peregrin - so my answer isn't useful for you because (a) you can't use `if constexpr` and (b) you can't detect the return type of `f()` through `std::function` and deduction guides. It's a pity.

Answer (score 2):

Well... if you can't use C++17 (so no template deduction guides for `std::function` and no `if constexpr`) the best I can imagine is define two overloaded function receiving an object, a method pointer for that object and parameters for the method.

```
template <typename T, typename ... As1, typename ... As2>
bool callFunc (T * pObj, bool(T::*f)(As1...), As2 && ... args)
 { return (pObj->*f)(std::forward<As2>(args)...); }

template <typename T, typename ... As1, typename ... As2>
bool callFunc (T * pObj, void(T::*f)(As1...), As2 && ... args)
 { (pObj->*f)(std::forward<As2>(args)...); return true; }
```

As you can see, the first one return the value returned from the method (a `bool` value); the second one call the method (returning `void`) and return a `true`.

Given this `callFunc()` couple, you can create a single `GenerateLambda()` as follows

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename ... As>
typename SFuncInfo<F>::Signature GenerateLambda (F f, T * pObj,
                                                 SParamsPack<As...>)
 {
   return [pObj, f](As && ... args)
    { return callFunc(pObj, f, std::forward<As>(args)...); };
 }
```

Comment: I think you can even simplify callFunc to

```
`template <typename T, typename ... Args>
bool callFunc (T * pObj, bool(T::*f)(Args...), Args&& ... args)
{ return (pObj->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`
```

Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Peregrin - No: it's important to maintain **two** separate sets of variadic template types or is very difficult get it working. Particularly if you want to work with perfect forwarding.